# Why is an exception message only a SQL Server column name?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, exception, stored-procedures, .net-2.0

We have error handling that logs exceptions into our database. An error is logging that is just a SQL Server column name, nothing more. The errors we log are the exception message concatenated with the inner exception. So we'd expect to see the kind of exception and more detail, but instead all we see is `ProblemField`

We are writing in C# on the .Net 2.0 Framework and using SQL Server 2005 for the DB.

Here's the code, along with issues I noticed.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProcedure", connection))
{
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PARAM1", var1);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PARAM2", var2);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PARAM3", var3);

   using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {
       if (rdr.HasRows)
       {
           rdr.Read();

           var4 = (double)rdr["ProblemField"];
           var5 = (double)rdr["OtherField"];
       }
       else
       {
           var4 = var5 = 0.0;
       }
   }
}
```

I changed these reads of `rdr["ProblemField"]` and `rdr["OtherField"]` to use a `Double.TryParse` instead.

Select of `MyStoredProcedure`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [anbrID]
        ,[col1]
        ,[col2]
        ,[col3]
        ,COALESCE([ProblemField], 0.0)
        ,COALESCE([OtherField], 0.0)
        ,[col6]
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE (col1=@PARAM1 OR
            CAST(@PARAM2 AS int) between CAST(col2 AS int) and CAST(col3 AS int)) AND
            col6 =@PARAM3
        ORDER BY id DESC
```

I have changed these `COALESCE`s to also have an as "ProblemField," etc..

Bottom line: Is this kind of exception message normal? Do my fixes seem reasonable for such a vague error?

Comment: You did not show where you logged the exception. Probably you just logged the field name. Show the line logging the exception

Comment: The exception logging we use is the same in all of our projects, and this is the only time we've seen this that I can recall. It takes an exception object and uses exception.Message + " - " + excption.InnerException

Comment: You should probably step through this code and see what actually happened. I guessed column name was not found or something else.

Comment: You might need to look at the `.InnerException` of your exceptions, too! Those often contain very valuable additional information! (and can be nested several levels deep)

Comment: You should log at least the type of the outer exception, and preferably log exception.ToString(), which includes any inner exceptions, the stack trace, and other useful data.  I suspect the outer exception is one you've generated yourself to wrap an inner SqlException.

Comment: are you using cutom Exception? I am facing similar issue and I am using custom Exception.

Comment: Can you please show how are you logging the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why (among other reasons) you should log the *whole* exception (using .ToString) so that you get the stacktrace and the exception type.

I'll hazard a guess though, that it's an ArgumentOutOfRangeException thrown by the SqlDataReader - I believe that only gives the field parameter without any other message. You currently have no 'as' for the coalesced columns which would definitely cause this. You say you added it, but I suspect it was incorrect somehow.